# Window position and size not saved when app is closed

Tags: development, vala, apps

I made this simple application and made it so that the window position and size is saved on closing the app, so that the next time the user opens the app, he can resume his work directly.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YJFU2u0LNC7YO3Hwk3ts32EDh-Q965Gi?usp=sharing

This is the link to the source code of my app.

Can anyone review the code and point out my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing one last step, actually calling the function that is supposed to save the new values in the gsettings schema. To do this, you need to connect the [delete_event](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Widget.delete_event.html) signal to your `before_destroy ()` function. I like to place that right before calling `show_all ()`:

[image]

Also, the `before_destroy ()` function must return `false` for the window to actually close.

[image]

EDIT: Please look into using a github repository, sharing google drive links is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.